# EF add-migration generates empty migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

I added into my model a new table:

```
public DbSet<ReturnedTransactions> ReturnedTransactions { get; set; }
```

And i want my migrations to generate that table for me, so i did:

```
PM> Add-migration returnedTransactions
```

And it generated

```
public partial class returnedTransactions : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

How do i force this thing to generate proper code for me?

Comment: What fields are in your table?  Can you show the class where you define the table?

Comment: Well it's a class with a bunch of fields, why does that matter?

Comment: Do you tried compile the project before?

Comment: It's possible that `ReturnedTransactions` was already created because it is referenced from another entity via foreign keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF migration shows empty Up() Down() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708519/ef-migration-shows-empty-up-down-methods)

Answer (score 3):

I see this happen when I do not add my DBSet Entity to my DbContext class that is associated with the Migration Configuration file.

Although, it may not be the case here as we can see that the Asker included the line:

```
public DbSet<ReturnedTransactions> ReturnedTransactions { get; set; }
```

Still, this is something one should check when they are returned an empty migration class.

Answer (score 1):

Clear out the `_MigrationHistory` table.

Comment: I would recommend against just randomly cleaning out `__MigrationHistory` table. That will cause Entity Framework to think that the migrations have run, and the tables have not been created. Then when Entity Framework runs the migrations, it will throw errors about the tables or columns existing. The better way is to use `Update-Database -Target:0` or similar command to remove things.

Answer (score 1):

Check the created table in the **"ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot"** class, This class is added to the Migrations folder when the first migration is made and updated with each subsequent migration. Try to clear the new table if it's there or deletes this class. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and I added -Force to the Add-Migration command and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That may sound stupid, but do you have all needed packages installed? I have had the same problem and it turned out that a packages was missing, I think it was Microsoft.AspNetCore or Mircosoft.AspNetMVC.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer, for me I had to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` through NuGet in an another project, which is connected with the one containing the database context.