# MVC migration is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, migration

I've added a simply Product-class (shown below) but when I run add-migration it generates an empty script. I guess this is hard to troubleshoot but any idea as to why this is?

public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

```
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The migration file looks like this:

public partial class test : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

```
    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Clearing out _MigrationHistory (and possible also opening your Project.Data.csproj to manually delete te migrations pending)

I found the answer here: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048025/ef-add-migration-generates-empty-migration)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the according Class to your DB context?

public System.Data.Entity.DbSet YourDbSetName { get; set; }